# How to run bash scripts on WSL

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to run a script `script.sh` from an Ubuntu WSL. In the Ubuntu WSL, calling `sh script.sh` simply returns without doing anything. Am I doing something wrong? what is the correct way to run Bash scripts in WSL?

I can run the script from Cygwin, so I know it is valid. The EOL is set to Unix. I've set permissions to 777. I've tried running it both from within the WSL interactive shell, and as a command from PowerShell: `bash script.sh`; neither works. I've tried `bash`, `sh`, `wsl`, `./`.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "hello"
```

Result from WSL:

```
~/test$ bash script.sh
~/test$
```

Result from Cygwin:

```
$ bash script.sh
hello

~/AppData/<path to ubuntu home>/test
$
```

Comment: Late to answer but someone visiting here - Also notice what are line endings in your script? It should be Linux style `\n` not `\r\n`

Comment: Unfortunately, I no longer have that WSL installation. I'll keep in mind line endings. My original script was written in Linux, but it's possible I opened it in an editor on Windows and broke it.

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to replicate this issue. I've submitted this as an answer in order to include code:

```
henry@TV:~
498$ cat <<, >script.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo hello
,

henry@TV:~
499$ bash script.sh
hello
```

*edit:* Please note that the `#!/bin/bash` shebang and `.sh` extension are unnecessary if you're going to call this directly with bash. Your `chmod` is only necessary if you're going to be calling it as an executable `./script`, in which case the shebang is required.

Comment: Huh. I thought I was doing something wrong. There might be something with my wsl installation then. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Ditto here, this issue isn't reproducible for me either.

Comment: I'm having that issue, did you ever figure it out?